# What is the difference between ViewPager and FlatList?

Tags: android-viewpager, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I think FlatList's pagingEnabled={true} is same  contributions with viewpager.
what diffrence between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flatlist is adapted for big data sources, which has the same layout for example, FeedList.

ViewPager is adapted for subscreens of particular screen eg
You have Onboarding Flow and you would like to swipe between the pages.

Ofc you can use ScrollView for it, but ViewPager does gestures on native side.

Comment: That's the exact answer I wanted. Thanks!